# Google Chrome kiosk mode - disable select and copy contextmenu

Tags: windows-7, windows, google-chrome, touchscreen, kiosk

I need to display an information website. The user should **only** be able to press buttons and use scrollbars through a touch screen.
The kiosk mode of Google Chrome fits this requirements pretty well.
However there are the following two problems:

1. When the user presses long on the screen, the text gets selected
2. If some text is selected a little (copy) context menu appears

[Click here for a screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36N29.png)

Details about my setup:

- Windows 7 64bit
- Google Chrome: Version 54.0.2840.99 m (64-bit)
- Google Chrome start parameters: -disable-pinch -overscroll-history-navigation=0 -kiosk

How can I prevent those two things from happening?
Is there a Google Chrome parameter, a Windows setting or something else?

Comment: Try looking under 'pen and touch settings' in the Windows Control Panel, I think there's an option to turn off long-pressing there.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @seagull There are to places where you can disable long-pressing. I did that and it works well for default windows programs like explorer.exe, desktop shortcuts etc. Google Chrome however ignores these settings. I'm still able to select text by long-pressing and the copy contextmenu still appears. Unfortunately this doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
--kiosk --incognito --no-context-menu
```

Should do the job

[Sources](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=23145)

Comment: This doesn't prevent the text selection + copy bubble as shown in his linked image.