# Chrome kiosk create infinite window

Tags: windows, windows-10, google-chrome, kiosk

### Context

I'm trying to configure Windows 10 to boot directly on chrome in kiosk mode so the user can only see the webpage.

So I've followed [those steps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/provisioning-packages/provisioning-install-icd) and launch Chrome in kiosk mode with the selected webpage.

### Issues

Unfortunately, there is one more problem :

When I reboot sometimes (Once in three) Chrome open an infinite amount of Chrome browser, not new tabs but new windows.

### Expectation

My needs for this system is to be fully optional anytime even if I ghost this OS on hundreds of device. So if anyone has an idea or suggestions, I will be thankful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `--kiosk --incognito --no-context-menu`

First I've only used `--kiosk` but while I was answering to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1148067/google-chrome-kiosk-mode-disable-select-and-copy-contextmenu/1293065#1293065) I try it in my case and it actually worked !

Hope it helped someone else too.